# Offer the option to send custom feedback on ads

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I noticed there was a typo in an ad for a service that I am familiar with:

[image]

So I thought I would click the 👎 and click "Other" but sadly this does not allow me to enter a custom reason. Instead now this ad is flagged as downvoted and I can't undo my actions.

Perhaps this feature could be expanded to allow some free text to be entered, which can be shared with the vendor / ad team.

Comment: *Hold on...let me get my glasses.*

Comment: So we can spam the ad agency, with a  and some free text? I don't know if it's a bad idea or a payback..

Comment: How would you filter out the 99 "YOUR SERVICE SUX!!!! CUCK" messages to get the one or two useful ones? One can already contact the SO team about stuff like this, they are usually very responsive.

Comment: You can do that by offering the ability to add custom text to verified users; and filtering our spam is a problem that has already been solved.

Comment: By "verified" you mean higher reputation? That's not a bad idea - but even high-reputation users might post stuff in the heat of the moment  (like when seeing a product they really really hate or think is unethical) that you don't want your ad customers to see, so you'd have to have someone at Stack Overflow process every piece of feedback that comes in. That sounds like a lot of work for relatively little gain. Is contacting the team manually not sufficient for the very very few instances when this is an issue?

Comment: Perhaps this should not be changed. It is a very useful clue as to the quality of a product when a simple ad that they are paying to display has not been spell-checked.

Comment: @Pekka웃 how do you contact the team manually? If you can post that as an answer, I think that solves it for me.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid if in doubt, `team@stackoverflow.com` is the catch-all go-to. It can take a while until they can respond, but I've never had an E-Mail go ignored. (Well, not any sent to the `team@` mail box.)

Comment: @CodyGray I used to think like you, until I realized that somebody's language skill has little to do with their work skill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implementing the feature is probably not viable, for the reasons discussed in the comments: this would need a moderation system, for relatively little benefit.

When you see a problem with an ad, you can contact the team manually: `team@stackoverflow.com`